# React multipages, component data passing

Tags: javascript, facebook, components

I'm doing a react app and id I'd like to know how to think multipages websites. Actually i'im I'm doing a course searcher,i searcher; I use routie to render the different components that renders render the page. The problem is that they arent aren't related by hierarchy, so the ajax data isn't accessible to the component that renders the result.I've I've tried vainly to use a js var data but doesnt var data but that doesn't work too either.Ive read https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html
but i don't see what to do with own event system. If someone could illustrate the last paragraph of this doc it is great for all the people that are in this case.

```
var data = {}; 

var CourseSearcher = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return {
   return {  places: '',
      branch: 0,
      dayOfMonth: '',
      timeStart: '',
      timeEnd: '',
      data: []};
    },;
  },
  handlePlacesChange: function(e){
        this.setState({places: e.target.value});
    },
    handleBranchChange: function(e){
        this.setState({branch: e.target.value});
    },
    handleDayOfMonthChange: function(e){
        this.setState({dayOfMonth: e.target.value});
    },
    handleTimeStartChange: function(e){
        this.setState({timeStart: e.target.value});
    },
    handleTimeEndChange: function(e){
        this.setState({timeEnd: e.target.value}); 
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e){
        // stop the default browser action
        e.preventDefault();
        // Do an ajax post
        $.ajax({
            url:'php/results.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
      data: {
       data: {places: this.state.places,
        branch:this.state.branch,
        dayOfMonth:this.state.dayOfMonth,
        timeStart:this.state.timeStart,
        timeEnd:this.state.timeEnd},
      },
      success: function(data){
                this.setState({data: data});
        data = this.state.data; 
        routie('results');
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr,status,err){
                console.error('php/results.php',status,err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
          <form method="get" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>Où?</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Lieux" 
                value={this.state.places} 
                onChange={this.handlePlacesChange} 
            />
            <label>Quoi?</label>
            <select value={this.state.branch} onChange={this.handleBranchChange}>
              <option>Matière</option>
              <option>Français</option>
              <option>Anglais</option>
            </select>
            <label>Quand ?</label>
            <input 
            type="date" 
            value={this.state.dayOfMonth} 
            onChange={this.handleDayOfMonthChange} 
            /> 
            <input 
            type="time" 
            value={this.state.timeStart} 
            onChange={this.handleTimeStartChange}
            /> - 
            <input 
            type="time" 
            value={this.state.timeEnd} 
            onChange={this.handleTimeEndChange}/>
            <button type="submit">Go!</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}); 

console.log(data); 

var ResultList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      console.log(data);
      return(
      <h1>Hello</h1>);
    }
);
  }
});

var ResultBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h4>{}</h4>
        </div>
      );

      }
});

routie({
        '':function() {
          React.render(<CourseSearcher />,
              document.getElementById('content'));
        },
        'results': function() {
    React.render(
      React.render(<ResultList results={data} />,
            document.getElementById('content'));
        }
      });
```

Done well with react router ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with react router where components are related to some dedicated urls